# Как показать только одну запись из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Как показать только одну запись из массива.

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=".$myrow["type"]."&owner_id=".$myrow["owner_id"]."&item_id=".$myrow["item_id"]."&filter=likes");
$resp = json_decode($response, true);

if (!in_array($check_like, $resp['response']['users'])) 
{
    echo $myrow["id"];    
}
```

Как показать `$myrow["id"];`  только один раз?

Вот полностью весь код:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM vk_likes 
    WHERE 
    sex='0' 
    AND country='0' 
    AND user_age_from='0' 
    AND user_age_to='100' 
    AND (need_likes>there_likes) 
    AND order_user_uid!='$check_like' ");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do
{
    $response = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=".$myrow["type"]."&owner_id=".$myrow["owner_id"]."&item_id=".$myrow["item_id"]."&filter=likes");
    $resp = json_decode($response, true);

    if (!in_array($check_like, $resp['response']['users'])) 
    {
        echo $myrow["id"];    
    } 
}
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: У вас в коде он выводится 1 раз.

Comment: @LEQADA нет много, а мне надо только первый результат.

Comment: В ходе выполнения кода Выводится 1,2,3,4,5 а нужто чтоб выводился только превый результат 1

Comment: @Анатолий в блоке `if` значит надо написать `break;` А вообще, если у вас список будет большой, а значение будет в конце, то вас контакт забанит за частое обращение к API

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это я делаю авторизацию через ссылку, пользователь в форму вставляет ссылку, я получаю с нее screen_name, далее предлагаю ему поставить лайк, ссылки для лайка выбераются с базы, а методом likes.getList проверяю чтобы отметки етого пользователя еще небыло, тоисть если в выбраной с базы ссылке уже есть отметка я ее не показываю а если нет тогда уже показую, после человек ставит лайк и скрипт проверяет поставлин ли он если да получаю остальную инфу о пользователи и далее регистрирую либо автризирую пользователя. А как уменьчить запросы к апи сам дума

Comment: @АлексейШиманский за break; спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @Анатолий, ну так в первоначальном варианте кода у вас не было никакого`while`.

Answer (score 1):

Переделать цикл так, чтобы прерывался после нахождения $myrow['id]. Например так:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vk_likes WHERE sex='0' AND country='0' AND user_age_from='0' AND user_age_to='100' AND (need_likes>there_likes) AND order_user_uid!='$check_like' ");
    $do = true;
    while($do && $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $response = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=".$myrow["type"]."&owner_id=".$myrow["owner_id"]."&item_id=".$myrow["item_id"]."&filter=likes");
        $resp = json_decode($response, true);
        if (!in_array($check_like, $resp['response']['users'])) 
        {
            echo $myrow["id"];
            $do = false;
        };
    }
```

Comment: мне кажется вместо `$do = false;` можно смело вписать `break;` 
а вообще я бы переделал все под PDO